# Android регистрация в сети всплывающее уведомление, как сделать?

Tags: php, android

Ситуация такая, необходимо реализовать уведомление пользователя что у него нет денег на счету или другую информацию для обязательного просмотра. 
Такое часто вижу в кафешках, ты подключаешься к wifi, а телефон сразу же открывает окно с приветствием и просьбой ввести номер. Я понимаю что это хотспот, но как эмулировать такую ситуацию? Т.е. есть заглушка которая уведомляет абонента что нет денег, но это только в браузере.

Comment: где реализовать на сайте или при подключение уточьните  вопрос?

Comment: на сайте, представьте что вы подключаетесь к сети, и Ваш весь трафик заворачивается на страницу сервер